# How to preload video of ProgressiveMediaSource like exoPlayer.prepare( ) method but without calling exoPlayer.prepare( )

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to preload videos without calling exoplayer prepare method.

I'm currently doing this:

```
        ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource=new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new CacheDataSource.Factory()
                .setCache(SimpleMediaPlayer.simpleCache)
                .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setUserAgent("ExoplayerDemo"))
                .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR))
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("https:xxxxxxx/Sending+Data+to+a+New+Activity+with+Intent+Extras.mp4"));
        ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
  player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
player.prepare();
```

I tried a method of `ProgressiveMediaSource` that is  `prepare source ()` I thought that was exactly what I'm searching but that is not loading the video.

I want to preload the video before playing like exoplayer.prepare(), exoplayer.prepare() is fine but I don't want to create an exoplayer instance in the background if there will be something available.